# How to access an image asset from a native module in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to access an image placed in some folder of my React Native project (let's say `project_root/Assets/Images/img.png`) in the native code of some module. I would like to solve this for Android first, and maybe iOS afterwards.

Also, how do I access asset images placed inside `android/src/main/assets` from another module? Is it possible? Is it any different?

Answer (score -3):

You can use the `<Image />` Component provided by the **react natiive** library.

```
      <Image
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={require('project_root/Assets/Images/img.png')}
      />
```

The project root being the path e.g: `../../src/`

Hope you understood.

And it is better to have images/assets in the assets folder. When you call the image using this component it will display it for both ios and android if nothing is wrong.

You can learn more about this [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image)

Comment: I want to access the image asset from the native side in Java code.